# Mysql where clause (search where table column match)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table, `t1`, around 500+ data row, I just show a sample data.

Data as below:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+
| id     | Name     | category          |
+--------+----------+-------------------+
| 1      | ABC      | 6,9,25,27         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

My mysql query like below:

```
$gcategory = intval($_GET['cat']);
$test = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE category like '%$gcategory%' ORDER BY id DESC");
foreach($test as $te){
    $list[] = $te;
}
```

But if `$gcategory = '7';` the `ABC` also will appear in my `$list[]`, but I just want when `$gcategory = '6' || $gcategory = '9' || $gcategory = '25' || $gcategory = '27'` then `ABC` only appear in my `$list[]`? how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try like following way, you should use find_in_set php function when you finding from , seperated list of value:

```
$gcategory = intval($_GET['cat']);
$test = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET("'.$gcategory.'", category) ORDER BY id DESC");
foreach($test as $te){
    $list[] = $te;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MySQL FIND_IN_SET()` function

You query will be like this

```
"SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET($gcategory,category) ORDER BY id DESC"
```